# django: passing urlencoded unicode strings to QueryDict produces incorrect results

Tags: python, django, unicode, urlencode

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
```

The following produces `u'Adam\xc3\xb3w'`, which I don't expect:

```
>>> QueryDict(u'search-search_term=Adam%C3%B3w')
<QueryDict: {u'search-search_term': [u'Adam\xc3\xb3w']}>
```

This produces the expected result: `u'Adam\xf3w'`:

```
>>> QueryDict('search-search_term=Adam%C3%B3w')
<QueryDict: {u'search-search_term': [u'Adam\xf3w']}>
```

In the first case, I pass unicode string to QueryDict whereas, in the second case, I pass bytestring to it. I am, however, still unusure about details of this behaviour. If anyone can explain why these two things produces different results, I would be glad.

Answer (score 0):

I think `QueryDict` expects a string as argument. So when you pass a unicode string, python try to convert it using the default converter, which is ascii. If you have a unicode string, you should convert it explicitly when passing it as an argument.

```
QueryDict((u'search-search_term=Adam%C3%B3w').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: encode('utf8') does solve the issue, however I still don't quite get why.